# in-place append while subclassing a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, append, subclass

I'd like to subclass the `list` object in Python, and add a method similar to the `append` method as well. I call it `append_` in the below example

```py
class MyList(list):
    def append_(self, element):
        new_list = list(self)
        new_list.append(element)
        self = self.__class__(new_list)
        return self
```

This is quite a simple example, but here is my problem: suppose I instantiate an object `my_list` with some list, and then I try to append an extra element to `my_list`

```py
my_list = MyList(list(range(5)))
my_list.append_(6) # returns [0,1,2,3,4,6]
# BUT 
my_list # returns [0,1,2,3,4]
```

so at the end I appended nothing. I do not understand neither what goes wrong nor where I may find help for this problem ...

I'm working with Python 3.9.12, if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to have a problem with the code as i am able to run it properly

[Works with repl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k43vP.png)

maybe try to put the code in a new file

The "_" was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I finally tried one more thing:

```py
class MyList(list):
    def append_(self, element):
        new_list = list(self)
        new_list.append(element)
        self.__init__(new_list)
        return self
```

that finally works as desired. I'm not sure I understand why, though, so I'd be glad if someone wants to elaborate more on this working solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your `append_()` function includes an underscore at the end of its name, you won't be appending anything to your list object when invoking it. So to get the correct result, you need to use `append()` without underscore:

```
class MyList(list):
    def append_(self, element):
        new_list = list(self)
        new_list.append(element)
        self = self.__class__(new_list)
        return self

my_list = MyList(list(range(5)))
print(my_list)
print(my_list.append(6))
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
None
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

In contrast, when you run the code with the function inside the class:

```
class MyList(list):
    def append_(self, element):
        new_list = list(self)
        new_list.append(element)
        self = self.__class__(new_list)
        return self

my_list = MyList(list(range(5)))
print(my_list)
print(my_list.append_(6))
print(my_list)
```

It prints the wrong output, not modifying the list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Also, you can change the `append_()` function to get the desired functionality:

```
class MyList(list):
    def append_(self, element):
        self.append(element)

my_list = MyList(list(range(5)))
print(my_list)
print(my_list.append_(6))
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
None
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: My bad, sorry there was a typo in the example, I want to add element via `append_` function, with the extra underscore. I corrected the question.

Comment: @fraschelle You can get the correct functionality for your class with `append()`.

Comment: @fraschelle I edited the answer with an alternative to `append_()` implementation